# dependencies for jsf (like servlet) prevent application from starting

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets, jsf-2

I have quite a big Java application that uses some jobs and a lot of http and db activity. This app was build using maven, has quite a lot dependencies and runs on tomcat 6 - good thing is, it works.

However, I now wanted to add some JSF functionality, namely I wanted to be able to manually start and stop quartz jobs from a website and so I activated two more dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
    <!-- to get the servlet container --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- To work with java server faces --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

After doing so, my app does not come up anymore. It starts, but I don't see any of my usual debugging messages, telling me that the app is actually doing something. It is also NOT crashing. It just seem to sit there, doing nothing. Strange thing is, the java class, that makes use of these dependencies is not even started.

Can anyone tell me, what it is with JSF? Do I have to do some fail over configuration, or anything???

I will attach a normal startup log and the one after activating these two dependencies.

***Normal startup:***

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[WARNING] 

[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for de.comlineag.snc:SocialNetworkConnector:war:0.2.5-SNAPSHOT

[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for ngdbc:ngdbc:jar should use a variable instead of a hard-coded path /Applications/eclipse/plugins/ngdbc.jar @ line 281, column 16

[WARNING] 

[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

[WARNING] 

[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.

[WARNING] 

[INFO]                                                                         

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Building Social Network Connector 0.2.5-SNAPSHOT

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] 

[INFO] >>> tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ SocialNetworkConnector >>>

[INFO] 

[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ SocialNetworkConnector ---

[debug] execute contextualize

[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.

[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory 
/Users/chris/Developer/workspace/socialnetworkconnector/src/main/resources

[INFO] 

[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ SocialNetworkConnector ---

[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

[INFO] 

[INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ SocialNetworkConnector <<<

[INFO] 

[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ SocialNetworkConnector ---

[INFO] Running war on http : // localhost : 8080 / SocialNetworkConnector

[INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at /Users/chris/Developer/workspace/socialnetworkconnector/target/tomcat Jul 26, 2014 11:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start

INFO: Starting tomcat server Jul 26, 2014 11:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start

INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29 Jul 26, 2014 11:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

INFO: Set web app root system property: 'webapp.root' = [/Users/chris/Developer/workspace/socialnetworkconnector/src/main/webapp/]
Jul 26, 2014 11:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

INFO: Initializing log4j from [/Users/chris/Developer/workspace/socialnetworkconnector/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/log4j.xml]
Jul 26, 2014 11:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext

INFO  ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started

INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Jul 26 23:54:38 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy

INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".

SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

INFO  DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase 2147483647

INFO  SchedulerFactoryBean - Starting Quartz Scheduler now

INFO  ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 808 ms

DEBUG GeneralConfiguration - using configuration file from job control src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/GeneralConfiguration.xml
Jul 26, 2014 11:54:39 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init

INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jul 26, 2014 11:54:39 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start

INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080

DEBUG ComplexXmlConfigurationPersistence - the domain Banking is active true and has priority 0
```

***Startup where nothing happens:***

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[WARNING] 

[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for de.comlineag.snc:SocialNetworkConnector:war:0.2.5-SNAPSHOT

[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for ngdbc:ngdbc:jar should use a variable instead of a hard-coded path /Applications/eclipse/plugins/ngdbc.jar @ line 280, column 16

[WARNING] 

[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

[WARNING] 

[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.

[WARNING] 

[INFO]                                                                         

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Building Social Network Connector 0.2.5-SNAPSHOT

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] 

[INFO] >>> tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ SocialNetworkConnector >>>

[INFO] 

[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ SocialNetworkConnector ---

[debug] execute contextualize

[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.

[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/chris/Developer/workspace/socialnetworkconnector/src/main/resources

[INFO] 

[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ SocialNetworkConnector ---

[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

[INFO] 

[INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ SocialNetworkConnector <<<

[INFO] 

[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ SocialNetworkConnector ---

[INFO] Running war on http : // localhost : 8080 / SocialNetworkConnector

[INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at /Users/chris/Developer/workspace/socialnetworkconnector/target/tomcat
Jul 26, 2014 11:46:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start

INFO: Starting tomcat server
Jul 26, 2014 11:46:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
     INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
     Jul 26, 2014 11:46:59 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
     INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
     Jul 26, 2014 11:46:59 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
     INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The servlet API you are including is most likely conflicting with the version provided by tomcat.  Use this dependency instead (replace version 6.0.41 with your version of tomcat):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.41</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Notice the scope is set to **provided**.  This means the jar will be used to compile your code but will not be included in your WAR file.  This is what you want since tomcat will provide the servlet api jar you need at runtime from its lib directory - hence no conflict.